# Does LIMIT clause makes updating faster? (Any database engine)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

For example:

`UPDATE tab_name SET col_name=? WHERE col_name='a_unique_str' LIMIT 1;`

The column `col_name` has no index, but we know the `'a_unique_str'` is indeed unique. Does `LIMIT 1` makes such a query faster?

(It's not difficult to do a simple benchmark, but I'd like to know if it works the same way in different databases, or any possible connection with database tuning.)

(Some databases like Oracle don't have `LIMIT`. I suppose they all have their equivalent clauses.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to know about a particular database, then you should test the code on that database.

However, the code *should* be faster.  The `limit 1` says to stop after one row has been updated, so it will stop after the first match.  With no `limit 1`, the database has to consider all rows that could match the conditions.  Without an index, this requires looking at the values in all the rows.

The improvement in speed could be very large, if the matching row is one of the first rows encountered.  Or, it could be negligible if the matching row is near the ned.  The expectation is that the query would do a full table scan, and the `limit 1` would save half the full table scan.